# Create a user for sharing purposes only

Tags: samba, file-sharing, users

I want to create simple user, who don't have any authority to use the system by logging in, but can access the resources shared on the network from a domain.

I am under an impression that samba user need an ubuntu user to run. So, I am not sure, if this is exactly what i want as well.

How to create such users?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a user under Ubuntu first.  To add a new Linux user account, simply:

1. Open ***System Settings***.
2. Choose ***User Accounts*** and unlock the panel using your administration password.
3. Use the + (plus) icon to create a new user.
4. Enter the new user’s full name (the user name will be filled in automatically based on the full name).

> As this folder is for ‘sharing purposes only’ do not assign
>   ‘administrative rights’ to this user account.  When finished, click
>   ***Create***. As the account is initially disabled, we now need to set the users password.
>
> Now when you return to the ‘Samba Users’ dialogue box and click ‘Add
>   User’, your new user account should be found in the Unix User name
>   drop-down box.

Source: [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba/)

Comment: OK. I am confused. `Samba Users` dialogue box, where did that came from.

Comment: From the (Samba Users dialogue box) Create New Samba User.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't need to create such a user.

Samba (in Ubuntu and in other operating systems) can be configured to provide resources, including shared folders, to anonymous users.

For example, to share a folder in Nautilus (the file browser) via Samba so that it's accessible over the network by anyone, without logging in, right-click on the folder, click Sharing Options, and check the box labeled `Guest access (for people without a user account)`.

[image: Folder Sharing dialog box in Nautilus showing the option to enable guest access]

This is just one example (of the most common sort of situation where one may want to enable guest access). If you need information about how to configure Samba for guest access manually (by editing configuration files) or for other resources (besides a shared folder), you can edit your question to provide details.

Comment: But, I didn't mean anonymous user. I want a authorized user, but without the privileges to access the system.