# Create a user for samba only (CLI)

Tags: command-line, samba

Exact same question as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152020/create-a-user-for-sharing-purposes-only), but using CLI instead of GUI.

I'd like to allow login access to a shared SMB directory, but the users get no other access to the server.

Comment: The question you refer to deals with guest access to samba, in other words everyone on the network has access to the share with no password. In your case, if that's what you want, what's the point of creating a special "user for samba only", if all have access anyway?

Comment: As the other asker also said, I do want logins and passwords for the file share.

Comment: Not sure what other asker you are talking about. See my answer below, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152020/create-a-user-for-sharing-purposes-only#comment-184235

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. Create a user on the server:

`sudo adduser --no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login sambausername`

2. Add that user to samba (you'll be asked to type a password):

`sudo smbpasswd -a sambausername`

3. Create a share by editing `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. For example, you can add something like this to the bottom:

   ```
   [share name]
       comment = whatever
       path = /path to share
       browsable = yes
       read only = no
       guest ok = no
   ```
4. Now is a good idea to restart samba:

`sudo service smbd force-reload`

5. Go to the client machine and try to access the share with the username and password you've just set up.

Comment: `--no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login` This saved my day! Still helpful in 2017!

Comment: @Stan Thanks for the feedback, glad it was helpful.

Comment: How do i use this user as a "valid users = <username>". For some reason this does not work? If i use the username of a user with a dashboard it will work. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: how can I do first step on centos?

Comment: maybe better: sudo adduser --no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos "" sambausername (where --gecos "" option to skip the chfn interactive part https://askubuntu.com/a/94067/828892 and uid < 1000 for hidden account https://askubuntu.com/a/22010/828892)

Answer (score 8):

**With Active Directory (Samba 4.0+)**

If you have Samba 4.x and it is connected to an Active Directory, you can use samba-tool to add a user to it:

```
samba-tool user add USERNAME-HERE
```

Please see [Samba AD DC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO) howto for more info

Answer Extracted from [Cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/)

To verify your Samba Version just user the command

```
samba -V
```

Example Output:

```
Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
```

Comment: Should this be the new accepted answer?

Comment: Scratch that. Didn't work after all :/ Seems that samba-tool is for Active Directory.

Comment: A Futher search shows that you need to config a Samba AD to use this feature.

Comment: Maybe the AD requirement should be more prominent?

Comment: In samba 4.7, I'm seeing "samba-tool user add" marked as deprecated. It seems it's now "samba-tool user create" that should be used. I confirm this is working, now as said in previous comments, this is for adding a user to an AD environment, not to a simple SMB file server as asked.

Comment: samba-tool is for Active Directory (AC) provisioning only https://askubuntu.com/a/490342/828892

Comment: I submitted an edit to clarify the AD relationship.